# Getting "tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified" on Python

Tags: python, sublimetext

While executing the command I am getting this "tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified" while running the commands on Python (Using Sublime text).

Can anyone let me know why I am getting this?[Screen Shot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayHX8.png)

Comment: What command are you executing? Please describe exactly what you are doing to generate the message. Are you invoking `tput` in your program?

Comment: Your question sounds suspiciously like you're trying to execute something that expects the Sublime output panel to be a terminal when it is not.